# How to count number in list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list of numbers from 1 to 20. Random 10 numbers.
I need to print how much does number 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.. until 20 appears in the list.

The problem is that when it counts it will count 11, 12, 13, 14 etc. as 1.
How can I set it when it comes to 11 it will NOT count it to 1, and if it comes to other numbers ex: 12,13,14, it will NOT count it to 1 or 2,3,4.

Thank you for answers!

```py
count = 0
f = open("numbers.txt")
for line in f:
    count += line.count("1")


print (count)
f.close()
```

Comment: can you tell the format in which no are stored in result.txt and what output you expect

Comment: They can be stored in any format.

Few lines from number.txt:
 
1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18 
1, 2, 5, 6, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20 
2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 19

Output: 
Num1 : 2
Num2 : 2
Num3 : 1
etc..

Comment: so in short you are are doing is read a text ile and count the frequency of a number , say '1' comes 12 times , 2 comes 3 times from [1,20]  right ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: your code is working fine i got same result for 1 ( no in new line) and in same line sep by space .

Answer (score 2):

The description is a bit ambiguous, so I'm taking a bit of a guess what you are looking for. Are you looking to print the numbers 1 to 20? If so, this is how I would do it:

**Printing to console**

```
for i in range(20):
  print(i + 1)
```

**Writing to file**

```
with open("numbers.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in range(20):
        f.write("{}\n".format(str(i + 1)))
```

If this is not what you are looking for, can you provide a bit more detail? Possibly expected input / output?

*Edit* If you're looking to count the instances in the file:

```
searchNum = 10
count = 0

with open("num.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if int(line.strip()) == searchNum:
            count += 1
```

`strip()` is used to remove any whitespace on the line

*edit edit* **Here is another style using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):**

```
searchNum = 10

with open("num.txt", "r") as f:
    list = [int(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
    count = list.count(searchNum)
```

Comment: How many times does the number ex: 1,2,3,4,5 appears in the numbers.txt file, but if I use count(1), it will count numbers 11,12,13,14,15... as 1.

Few lines from number.txt:
 
1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18 
1, 2, 5, 6, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20 
2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 19

Expected Output: 
Num1 : 2
Num2 : 2
Num3 : 1
etc..

But got:
Num1: 19

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by converting the string into an integer for each line. 
For one number in each

```
for line in f:
    count += 1 if int(line) == 1
```

If the file has multiple integers per line :

```
for line in f:
    num_arr = line.split(' ')
    count += num_arr.count('1') #this works now since num_arr is a list of string
```

Answer (score 1):

You are now counting **digit characters** in every line.

```py
for line in f:  # line is string
    count += line.count("1")  # oh no! digit characters are counted!
```

To solve the problem, you must restore the real list of **number**.

To get the list of "number", you can split the content by whitespaces. The "number"s are now strings.

```py
number_in_str = f.read().split()
```

Next, convert it to number, then count.

```py
numbers_list = [int(u) for u in number_in_str]

count = numbers_list.count(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(r"result.txt").read()
count = f.count('1')
print(count)
```

output

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 

import re

count = 0
count2 = 0
num1 = '1'
num2 = '2'




with open('numbers.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
        for line in row:
            if line == num1:
                count += 1
            elif line == num2:
                count2 += 1

print("Num1: "), count
print("Num2: "), count2
```